# Trying to implement RBtree in C

Tags: c

I tried to implement RB tree in C but the compiler always failed on specific error: "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

I declared the following Struct:

```
`typedef struct costumer_tree  
{
    int id;
    char lastName[100];
    int color;
    struct costumers_tree * left;
    struct costumers_tree * right;
    struct costumers_tree * parent;
}
costumerTree;`
```

And use the RBfix function:

```
`treeInsertFixup(costumerTree *costumerTreeRoot, costumerTree *z)
{
costumerTree *y;
while (z->parent->color == 2)
{
...}`
```

But when i compile the code the compile always failed on the row:
`while (z->parent->color == 2)`
With the error: "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

Why am i missong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct costumers_tree` was never defined; `struct costumer_tree` was.

Comment: ohh shame me, it took me a while , thank you very much!!